# Lifetime of lambda captured references in const lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, constants, c++14

I have the following api:

```
old_operation(stream, format, varArgs);
```

And I want to write an adaptor to make it possible to write the call as follows:

```
stream << operation(format, varArgs);
```

To do this I'm using a temporary object which stores references to varArgs and overload the `operator<<` to apply the `old_operation()` as follows:

```
template<typename ...T>
decltype(auto) storage(T&& ...t) {
   return [&](auto&& f) ->decltype(auto) {
       return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(t...);
   };
}

template<typename ...T>
class Operation
{
    using Storage = decltype(storage(std::declval<T>()...));
    public:
       template<typename ...Args>
       explicit Operation(Args&& ...args) : 
               mArgs(storage(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {};
       template<class StreamType>
       StreamType& Apply(StreamType& stream)
       {
           auto f = [&](auto&& ...xs)
           {
               old_operation(stream, std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...);
           }
           mArgs(f);
           return stream;
       }
   private:
       Storage mArgs;
};

template<typename ...Args>
Operation<Args...> MakeOperation(Args&&... args)
{
    return Operation<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class StreamType, typename ...Args>
StreamType& operator<<(StreamType& stream, Operation<Args...>&& operation)
{
    return operation.Apply(stream);
}
```

This works great but now I need to add some `using namespace` declarations embedded into the operation call:

let's say I have

```
namespace X {namespace Y { namespace Z { int formater(double x) { return std::round(x); }}}
```

And I don't want to add all the namespaces for this call, so I'm doing something like:

```
#define OPERATION(...) \
   [&]() { \
        using namespace ::X:Y:Z; \
        return Operation("" __VA_ARGS__); }() \
```

which allows me to do:

```
stream << OPERATION(format, formater(2.3));
```

The problem with the lambda is that the temporaries are being created in a different scope than the `Apply()` call, which is UB.

I don't know if by adding a const qualifier to mArgs it will prolong the life of the captured references as mentioned [here](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). I'm not sure if this applies, I'm assuming they are stack-based references and that by adding the const qualifier to mArgs the qualifier is going to be applied to the captured references.

Comment: Extending the lifetime of a temporary with a `const &` only applies to local function variables.  You cannot pass a temporary to a class and then hold on to it with a `const &`.

Comment: I was afraid of that, I will keep trying to find a different solution then

Comment: I am wondering why something as simple as `template <typename Stream, typename Format, typename... Rest>
Stream& operator<<(Stream& strm, Format&& f, Rest&&... vargs) {
  old_operation(stm, std::forward<Format>(f), std::forward<Rest>(vargs)...);
  return strm;
}` won't work for you? Just asking out of curiousity.

Comment: operator << must take exactly two arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename ...T>
decltype(auto) storage(T&& ...t) {
  return [&](auto&& f) ->decltype(auto) {
    return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(t...);
  };
}
```

this is a haskell-style functor (well, a variardic one, which isn't very haskell).  It takes `Ts...` and returns a function of type `((Ts...)->U)->U`, ie that knows how to evaluate a function on the arguments you passed to it.  This makes `storage` of type `(Ts...)->( ((Ts...)->U)->U )` for a bit of algebraic fun.

I suspect your problem is that you have temporaries that you don't store.  Generally not storing temporaries passed to a function, where the return value depends on the lifetime of those temporaries, results in fragile code.

If you have C++1z `experimental::apply` we can do this:

```
template<class... Ts>
decltype(auto) storage(Ts&&... ts) {
  return
    [tup=std::tuple<Ts...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)]
    (auto&& f)
    ->decltype(auto) mutable
  {
    return std::experimental::apply(decltype(f)(f), std::move(tup));
  };
}
```

which returns a one-shot delayed call to `std::apply`.  Apply takes a function and a tuple, and passes the arguments of the tuple to the function.  It handles reference and r/lvalue-ness properly.  Meanwhile, the container of the tuple makes the capture simpler, and lets us easily conditionally store rvalues while keeping lvalues as references.

I think this solves your problem, as temporaries get moved-into the tuple instead of being captured by reference, while non-temporaries are stored by reference.

There should be `std::experimental::apply` implementations that are better than anything I can sketch here available easily.

Comment: nice, I was doing something similar before, but instead of storing a lambda with a tuple inside my `operation` object I was storing the tuple, then I was unpacking the tuple directly into the `old_operation` inside the `Apply` call , but I wasn't totally convinced of using tuples because the long compilation times